# How to find sibling element with behat/mink?

Tags: dom, behat, siblings, mink

HTML:

```
<div id="my-id">
    <li class="list_element">
        <div class="my_class"></div>
        <a href=""></a>
    </li>
    <li class="list_element">
        <div class="another_class"></div>
        <a href=""></a>
    </li>
    <li class="list_element">
        <div class="class3"></div>
        <a href=""></a>
    </li>
</div>
```

What I want to do with behat/mink:

```
$page = $this->getSession()->getPage();
$selector = $page->find('css', "#my-id .my_class"); //here I need anchor element located near to .my_class div.
```

I don't know in which one `.list_element` `.my_class` div is. I know only anchor is next to `.my_class` element. Which selector should I use in the find() function?

Comment: As interesting as this challenge is from a coding point of view it's breaking away from Behat and Mink's core purpose and any solution would be an abuse of the technology. Testing for sibling elements by class name is not really in the spirit of user acceptance testing because it is not concerned with ensuring content is available to users. This feels more like it should be covered by a PHPUnit test on the helper that generates your markup.

Comment: I do see a requirement for checking sibling content so I wrote this Q&A: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49050631/behat-mink-check-for-some-text-followed-by-some-text-in-sibling-elements/49050632

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try one of these:

```css
#my-id .my_class ~ a

#my-id .my_class + p

#my-id .list_element a
```

This is too basic question.Please see more here [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)