# Behat (+ Mink) Check for some text followed by some text (in sibling elements)

Tags: behat, mink

The `I should see...` function is an essential feature of Behat but I regularly find myself wanting to write something like this in my scenarios:

```
Then I should see "Session ID" followed by "3"
```

Which is my humanly-parsable way of describing 2 pieces of text next to each other in the content. That is to say the first string is the content of any element and the second is the content of it's next immediate sibling.

This would be useful for checking *label - value* type layouts:

[image: Screenshot of layout with sibling content]

Or if I want to check *header - cell value* type layouts in tabulated data:

[image: Screenshot of tabulated layout with sibling content]

Or even definition title - definition.

Obviously I could add 'id' attributes to every element I want to test but in a complicated page where many parts of the content need testing this starts to feel like I am bloating the markup with single-use attributes.

Comment: As a general rule, it is better to post some html snippets rather than photos of the section.

Answer (score 2):

To be able to use...

```
Then I should see "Session ID" followed by "3"
```

Add the following methods to your `FeatureContext.php` file:

```
/**
 * @Then I should see :textA followed by :textB
 */
public function iShouldSeeFollowedBy($textA, $textB)
{
    $content = $this->getSession()->getPage()->getContent();

    // Get rid of stuff between script tags
    $content = $this->removeContentBetweenTags('script', $content);

    // ...and stuff between style tags
    $content = $this->removeContentBetweenTags('style', $content);

    $content = preg_replace('/<[^>]+>/', ' ',$content);

    // Replace line breaks and tabs with a single space character
    $content = preg_replace('/[\n\r\t]+/', ' ',$content);

    $content = preg_replace('/ {2,}/', ' ',$content);

    if (strpos($content,$textA) === false) {
        throw new Exception(sprintf('"%s" was not found in the page', $textA));
    }

    $seeking = $textA . ' ' . $textB;
    if (strpos($content,$textA . ' ' . $textB) === false) {
        // Be helpful by finding the 10 characters that did follow $textA
        preg_match('/' . $textA . ' [^ ]+/',$content,$matches);
        throw new Exception(sprintf('"%s" was not found, found "%s" instead', $seeking, $matches[0]));
    }
}


/**
 * @param string $tagName - The name of the tag, eg. 'script', 'style'
 * @param string $content
 *
 * @return string
 */
private function removeContentBetweenTags($tagName,$content)
{
    $parts = explode('<' . $tagName, $content);

    $keepers = [];

    // We always want to keep the first part
    $keepers[] = $parts[0];

    foreach ($parts as $part) {
        $subparts = explode('</' . $tagName . '>', $part);
        if (count($subparts) > 1) {
            $keepers[] = $subparts[1];
        }
    }

    return implode('', $keepers);
}
```